# using threading for multiple requests

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, asynchronous

In order to test our server we designed a test that sends a lot of requests with JSON payload and compares the response it gets back.

I'm currently trying to find a way to optimize the process by using multi threads to do so. I didn't find any solution for the problem that I'm facing though.

I have a url address and a bunch of JSON files (these files hold the requests, and for each request file there is an 'expected response' JSON to compare the response to).
I would like to use multi threading to send all these requests and still be able to match the response that I get back to the request I sent.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can use `communicate()`

Comment: @MaheshKaria can you expand o?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have couple of options:

1. Use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` (Python 2.7) where you create pool of threads and then use them for dispatching requests. `map_async` may be of interest here if you want to make async requests,
2. Use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` (Python 3) with similar way of working with `ThreadPool` pool and yet it is used for asynchronously executing callables,
3. You even have option of using `multiprocessing.Pool`, but I'm not sure if that will give you any benefit since everything you will be doing is I/O bound, so threads should do just fine,
4. You can make asynchronous requests with `Twisted` or `asyncio` but that may require a bit more learning if you are not accustomed to asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 0):

Use python multiprocessing `threadpool` where you can get `return value`  can be compared.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html
https://gist.github.com/wrunk/b689be4b59270c32441c